# Class not updated in g.i.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have this class

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public Question this[int i]
    {
        get { return Questions[i]; }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to use it on my page with

```
Questionnaire questionnaire;

protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{
    questionnaire.Questions = new List<Question>();
}
```

But I just keep getting

> 'Questionnaire' does not contain a definition for 'Questions' and no extension method 'Questions' accepting a first argument of type 'Questionnaire' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I noticed that I **can** seem to call

```
questionnaire.QuestionNumber = 1;
```

Even though I removed the `QuestionNumber` property ages ago.

Following the reference I can see that in `Questionnaire.g.i.cs` there is a `QuestionNumber` property but no `Questions` property.

I tried restarting VS, cleaning project, rebuilding the project but this achieved nothing.

Comment: Check your project references for the library that contains that `Questionnaire` code. I am willing to bet it is pointing to a place on disk instead of being added as a project reference.

Comment: `Questionnaire.g.i.cs` sounds like auto-generated code. Are you sure your class shouldn't be a `partial` class. Also you probably want to find out what's generating `QuestionNumber` if it was supposed to be removed.

Comment: Add this property by youself, just for fun I suppose)

Comment: Where is this class situated, inside cshtml ????

Comment: Is this blazor 0.1? or 0.2?

Comment: @VibeeshanRC Its in a seperate file in `Application.Models` namespace.

Comment: @Flores Its the latest version (I installed it yesterday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have a page that is also called Questionnaire (Questionnaire.cshtml). In Blazor apps each .cshtml file is used to generate a class at build time that has the same name as the .cshtml file. So you probably have two Questionnaire classes: the one you defined yourself, and the one generated from the Questionnaire file. Renaming one of the two classes should fix the issue.